# After creating files via shell script, can it also be used to select those files in Finder?

Tags: bash, macos-sierra, automator, finder

I have an Automator service using shell script to create symbolic links for files/folders selected in Finder. But is there some way I could also make it select the symbolic links that are created in Finder after creating them?

Here's the script, run as /bin/bash:

```
for f in "$@"
    do  ln -s "$f" "${f}.deleteThisExtensionAfterMoving"
done
```

Hopefully there is a way to do this. If anyone knows how, please answer and let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Would the `Reveal Finder Items` action work?

Comment: Not sure. But I also haven't figured out how to return the list of file names created by this script so that they're passed to any other steps after this in the automator workflow.

Comment: The output from the `Run Shell Script` action is what gets passed to the following action.  If the command(s) do not return anything, you can just echo the item (this is all the default script does).

Comment: i think when i run it i get the input files returned from the shell script instead of the symlink files it's creating. how would i echo the created files to be returned for this script? maybe submit that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ln` command doesn't return the path of the created link, but the script can `echo` the link path so that it can be passed on to the next action.  The following example workflow will reveal the created links in the Finder (note that there isn't any error handling):

**Ask for Finder Items** (or whatever)

**Run Shell Script** {pass input as arguments}

```
   for f in "$@"
   do
      ln -s "$f" "${f}.deleteThisExtensionAfterMoving"
      echo "${f}.deleteThisExtensionAfterMoving"
   done
```

**Reveal Finder Items**